# Efficient image translation by (x,y) pixels?

Tags: c, image, image-processing, opencv

Looking to see if anyone can recommend a computationally efficient method for translating/shifting an image by (x,y) pixels.

Reason being, I have been part successful in implementing the fourier-mellin transform to determine the rotation and translation between image frames. Once the image is unrotated I would like to untranslate the image by the calculated pixel offset (x,y). Allowing me to test the image correlation after rotation and translation.

Comment: I had a homework few months before that I have to optimize a program that take an image  , translate it to pixel and than rotate it by 90 degrees . you can download it from https://sites.google.com/site/matankeidarhomepage/89-230/exercises/ex5_source.zip?attredirects=0&d=1 . It work in linux environment and you should install "sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev" before  , and than run it with "./showBMP{a,b} <imageName>"

Answer (score 0):

I would think that a efficient method would be to:

1. Make a border `cv::copyMakeBorder()`.
2. Use a ROI e.g. make a new matrix header without copying data.

Good luck

Comment: I was looking at using ROI and essentially creating a second image by shifting the ROI based on (x,y). Trying to investigate a simple function which i could implement to pass in the original image and the translation parameters (x,y), returning the new translated image.

Comment: What is wrong with implementing you own functions that 1) makes border and 2)create a new matrix header ? Is it too slow ?